# How to use makefile vpath

Tags: makefile

This, simplified, makefile works perfectly

```
# folder for .o files
ODIR=./obj

$(ODIR)/cutest.o :
    g++ -o  $(ODIR)/cutest.o -c ../../../raven-set/cutest.cpp
```

This one, trying to use vpath, fails

```
#source file search paths
vpath %.cpp ../../../raven-set

# folder for .o files
ODIR=./obj

$(ODIR)/cutest.o :
    g++ -o  $(ODIR)/cutest.o -c cutest.cpp
```

like this

```
g++ -o  ./obj/cutest.o -c cutest.cpp
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: cutest.cpp: No such file or directory
```

On @MadScientist suggestion:

```
# folder for .o files
ODIR=./obj

$(ODIR)/cutest.o : cutest.cpp
        g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

but this fails too

```
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'cutest.cpp', needed by 'obj/cutest.o'.  Stop.
```

Comment: do not use `vpath`, it is a bad practice, as there could be name collisions of same named sources in different directories

Comment: @igagis  I have given up on using vpath - it does not work

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/cppfw/prorab it might solve all your problems with makefiles

Answer (score -1):

Make is not going to look through the text of your compile command and try to find references to prerequisite strings and replace them.

Make *only* replaces make variables.

So you should use an [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in your recipe:

```
$(ODIR)/cutest.o : cutest.cpp
        g++ -o $@ -c $<
```

**ETA** this works for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
vpath %.cpp src
obj/cutest.o : cutest.cpp
        g++ -o $@ -c $<

$ mkdir src
$ touch src/cutest.cpp

$ make
g++ -o obj/cutest.o -c src/cutest.cpp
```

Comment: I do not understand this answer.  I tried using your "automatic variable" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll have to be more clear about what about the answer you don't understand.  The solution does work (see my update) so if it doesn't work for you there must be some aspect of your environment you haven't described to us.  I'm assuming that the file `../../../raven-set/cutest.cpp` actually exists, starting with the directory you are in when you run `make`?

Comment: "I'm assuming ... actually exists."  Yes.  As shown by the first version that does work

Comment: I don't understand 1) make variables 2) automatic varables 4) " $@ -c $<"

Comment: I put a link to explain automatic variables above.  If you don't understand make variables at all then I think you need to do some reading on your own: stackoverflow is a place to get specific, detailed problems solved.  It's not a tutorial or user's manual.  See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html